# Subquery returned more than 1 value - trying to print names of databases

Tags: sql

I am trying to find and display a list of database names that are in anything but an ideal mirrored state. The below code works when one database is in such a state, but when more than that is errored I get the error this question refers to: **Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

Here's my code:

declare @result int
    declare @dbs varchar(256)

```
SET @result = (SELECT database_id from sys.database_mirroring WHERE mirroring_state_desc in ('SUSPENDED','DISCONNECTED','PENDING_FAILOVER'))
SET @dbs = (SELECT name from sys.databases where database_id = @result)

if @@ROWCOUNT > 0

print @dbs
```

Thank you very much any assistance,

Brad.

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. What is your question?

Comment: Since , you are trying to store a collection of values into a single variable..you are getting that error

Comment: I should've been more specific but yes, I understand what the error says, I was asking for a way to get around it.. I thought that was implied but apologies if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need `print` ? Maybe try to display list of db that way:

```
SELECT name 
from sys.databases 
where database_id in (SELECT database_id 
                      from sys.database_mirroring 
                      WHERE mirroring_state_desc in ('SUSPENDED','DISCONNECTED','PENDING_FAILOVER')
                     )
```

Comment: @Parado niceunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

select database_id  into #temp1  from sys.database_mirroring WHERE WHERE mirroring_state_desc in ('SUSPENDED','DISCONNECTED','PENDING_FAILOVER'))

SELECT name from sys.databases where database_id in #temp1

Where #temp1 is your temporary table